# Squid - Setup hits for each domain

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, http-proxy, squid

I am new to squid and I would like to know is there an option in  squid to set number of hits per domain per day when users are using proxy. For example I would like to set up 100 hits as limit to site http://example.com and when the limit is crossed we need to block the domain.

Any suggestions are appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no, there is no Squid option to limit the number of hits against a domain.  Squid does have the ability to launch custom scripts and connect to them on stdin/stdout though, sending data to the script & using its responses to control whether it will allow or deny a request.  You could use that functionality to solve this problem.  Two approaches I can think of:

**Option 1:** write a helper to accept the domain being accessed, and maintain a tally of all the domains it has seen and the number of times each one has been accessed, then return a response to Squid indicating whether the domain is over/under threshold, which Squid uses to allow/deny the request.  The advantage with this approach is that all the logic would be contained in one script.  The disadvantage is that Squid will dynamically launch multiple helpers in response to load, which means you would need to come up with a way for each instance of the script to share state, and shutdown/startup of the Squid process.

**Option 2:** split the above logic into two scripts, one to watch the logfile and maintain a tally of how many times each domain has been accessed, and a second script which Squid can launch as an external helper, to consult the tally maintained by the first script and return a response to Squid indicating whether the domain is over or under threshold.  The advantage with this approach is that it can scale out to support multiple helpers, and also survives a reload/restart of the Squid process.

First, your Squid configuration:

```
logformat domainonly %>rd
access_log daemon:/tmp/domains.log logformat=domainonly
external_acl_type domaincheck concurrency=0 %>rd /tmp/domaincheck.pl
acl overlimit-domains external domaincheck
http_access deny overlimit-domains
```

Second, a script to watch the log.  I recommend you place this in your crontab and fire it off at an interval which balances the load on your system, vs how much over-limit access you are willing to tolerate before hits become visible in the tally files, & blocked by Squid.  You should also make sure Squid rotates your logs once a day, and set up a separate script to run at midnight to clear out all the files in $basedir, to zero out the tally files in preparation for the next day.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# File:/tmp/domainwatch.pl
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
my $basedir = '/tmp/domaincntrs';
my $ptrfile = $basedir."/logpos.txt";
my $logfile = '/tmp/domains.log';
my $logpos = 0;

# Get last log position from pointerfile, detect if it has wrapped
if (open(INFILE, "<$ptrfile")) {
    $logpos = <INFILE>;
    close(INFILE);
    $logpos = 0 if ($logpos > (-s $logfile));
}

# Open logfile, seek and begin reading
my %domainhash;
if (open(LOGFILE, "<$logfile")) {
    seek (LOGFILE, $logpos, 0);
    while (my $domain = <LOGFILE>) {
        chomp($domain);
        $domainhash{$domain} = $domainhash{$domain} + 1;
    }
    $logpos = tell(LOGFILE);
    close(LOGFILE);
} else {
    print "could not open logfile $logfile: $!\n";
}

# Iterate over entries learned from log and increment counter files for each domain
foreach my $domain (keys(%domainhash)) {
    my $cntr = 0;
    # Get current counter
    if (open(CNTRFILE, "<".$basedir."/".$domain)) {
        $cntr = <CNTRFILE>;
        close(CNTRFILE);
    }
    # Write new counter
    if (open(CNTRFILE, ">".$basedir."/".$domain)) {
        print CNTRFILE ($cntr + $domainhash{$domain});
        close(CNTRFILE);
    }   
}

# Write current log position back to pointer file
if (open (PTRFILE, ">$ptrfile")) {
    print PTRFILE $logpos;
    close PTRFILE;
} else {
    print "could not write to pointerfile $ptrfile: $!\n";
}
```

And finally, a helper script which Squid can use to make policy decisions:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# File:/tmp/domaincheck.pl
use strict;

# Enable autoflush
$|=1;
my $basedir = '/tmp/domaincntrs';

# Set up infinite loop
while (my $line = <STDIN>) {
    my ($domain, $limit, $rest) = split(/\s+/, $line, 3);
    chomp($line);
    $limit = 100 if (!int($limit));
    my $cntr = 0;
    my $resp = '';
    if (open(INFILE, $basedir."/".$domain)) {
        $cntr = <INFILE>;
        close(INFILE);
    }
    chomp($cntr);
    $resp = ($cntr > $limit) ? 'OK' : 'ERR';
    if (open(LOGFILE, ">>/tmp/domaincheck.log")) {
        print LOGFILE "domain=$domain limit=$limit cntr=$cntr resp=$resp\n";
        close(LOGFILE);
    }
    print "$resp\n";
}
```

Some tips for tuning: you're going to get a lot of hits in the domains.log for access you might not expect, eg. even for entries which are denied.  You should consider setting up an ACL to define successful requests (eg, HTTP result codes 200-299) and then apply that ACL to the access_log statement, to control what gets written to that file.

The domaincheck.pl script has a default limit of 100, but will accept variable limits passed to it from the Squid configuration file.  You can use this to specify multiple invocations of that ACL in your squid.conf, eg:

```
# Define our busy and quiet domains
acl busy-domains dstdomain .google.com .microsoft.com
acl quiet-domains dstdomain .centos.org .adobe.com
# Define some busy and quiet limits
acl busy-domains-limit external domaincheck 750
acl quiet-domains-limit external domaincheck 100
# Combine the domains and limits ACLs into policy rules to deny access when both conditions are true
http_access deny busy-domains busy-domains-limit
http_access deny quiet-domains quiet-domains-limit
```

Repeat this for as many domain/limit thresholds as you need.

Comment: `FATAL: Bungled /usr/local/squid/etc/squid.conf line 35: acl overlimit-domains external 100
Squid Cache (Version 3.5.24): Terminated abnormally.
CPU Usage: 0.050 seconds = 0.050 user + 0.000 sys
Maximum Resident Size: 36784 KB
Page faults with physical i/o: 0` seeing this error when 100 is appended

Comment: It looks like you're missing the keyword "domaincheck" there.  So the line should be: acl overlimit-domains external domaincheck 100
Also, the domaincheck.pl script would need to be adjusted to take into account the extra parameter being passed to it from the Squid configuration file.  Would you be able to mark this as answered?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include the necessary changes to the domaincheck.pl script and also provided a configuration example.  HtH.

Comment: I set the limit to 10 for adobe.com but the domain is not blocked after 10 hits.May I know how do I make sure that domaincheck.pl is running and counting the hits every time when request is given from client.

Comment: `logformat domainonly %>rd access_log daemon:/tmp/domains.log logformat=domainonly external_acl_type domaincheck concurrency=0 %>rd /tmp/domaincheck.pl acl busy-domains dstdomain adobe.com acl busy-domains-limit external domaincheck 10 http_access deny busy-domains busy-domains-limit`.Able to hit the domain after crossing the limit `hostname% cat www.adobe.com 12;testvm$ curl -sL -x hostname:3128 -w '%{http_code}\n' "www.adobe.com" -o /dev/null 200`

Comment: Updated domaincheck.pl script, it also writes to a log - try that

Comment: you could also consider adding ttl=0 and negative_ttl=0 to the external_acl_type statement in squid.conf - this will cause Squid to consult the helper for every request, which means more load, but better logging.

Comment: Working as expected. Thanks so much for your help .. :) and finally thing I could see /tmp/domain.log is pulling all the domain data and making domainwatch.pl to create all the domain files which I don't require. Is there a way to log only the domains in /tmp/domain.log which I want to monitor so the domainwatch.pl can take less time in creating the domain files

Comment: Yes there is a way but it's related to Squid rule processing, not really part of your original question.  Can you mark my response as the accepted answer, then open a new question and I'll answer it there?

Comment: I don't have any enough reputation value to vote the answer

Comment: You may need reputation to vote, but as the person who asked, not to accept.  See the Help Center article on [Accepting an Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)